# Lodash - Remove one property for every element in array without specify index

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm building a component that allows me to compare two objects. It accepts a list of fields to compare and a list of fields that need to be ignored **in string format**

Here is an example of the object that will be compared:

```json
{

// (..... More elements above .....)

taskData: {
    "uniqueId": "OrdenTrabajo48",
    "id": 48,
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Dirección Obra Civil",
    "description": "Dirección Obra Civil Afecta: Sorda, Roberto",
    "startDate": "2021-10-16T11:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-06-01T11:00:00.000Z",
    "duration": 227,
    "progress": 73,
    "hours": 0,
    "realHours": 15,
    "predecessor": null,
    "child": [],
    "resourceInfo": [
        {
            "uniqueId": "Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "id": "OrdenTrabajo48Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "name": "Sorda, Roberto",
            "group": "Subgerencia de Planes y Proyectos - SUB_PLAN_PROY_SIT",
            "unit": 4.1667,
            "startDate": "2021-10-16T03:00:00.000+00:00",
            "endDate": "2022-06-01T02:59:59.000+00:00",
            "hours": 0,
            "realHours": 15,
            "avatar": "http://localhost:8091/images/llama.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "comments": null,
    "etiquetas": [],
    "baseLineStartDate": null,
    "baseLineEndDate": null
}

// (..... More elements below .....)

}
```

(But to clarify, it could be any object. The component is abstract and can be used anywhere)

**The component doesn't know the structure of the object to compare, just the object and the paths in string format**

I want to remove in every element of the array `resourceInfo`, the properties `avatar`, `icon`, `label` and `color` regardless the length of the array, but I don't know if there is a syntax to do that.

Also I want to remove the property `realHours`

This is what I tried:

```js
const ignoredFields = [
'taskData.resourceInfo[?].avatar',    //<--- It's not working
'taskData.resourceInfo[].icon',      //<---  Neither this
'taskData.resourceInfo.label',     //<--- Or this
'taskData.resourceInfo[0].color',     //<--- This hardcode is working, but I don't know the length in that scope
'taskData.realHours' // <-- No problems here

];

const currentComparableObject = _.omit(obj, ignoredFields);
const oldComparableObject = _.omit(prev, ignoredFields);
```

Comment: I would add another step and use path `taskData.resourceInfo` and iterate that array and omit array fields `['avatar','icon','label']` etc on each object

Comment: Right, how I could make it abstract? The component that compares two objects doesn't really know the details of the object that need to compare. It just knows an object and the names of the properties that need to ignore

Comment: Then you would need to recursively keep track of paths and walk through both objects simultaneously if you don't know the structure. I'm now a bit confused since you appeared to know what paths you wanted

Comment: I know the paths that I want to compare and ignore (A parent component offers those), but I don't know the structure of the model in the abstract component

Answer (score 2):

```
var fieldsToOmit=[];
var resourceInfoFields=['avatar','icon','label','color'];
var globalFields=['realHours'];
taskData.resourceInfo.forEach((item,index)=>{
  resourceInfoFields.forEach((field)=>{
    fieldsToOmit.push(`resourceInfo[${index}].${field}`)
  })
})
console.log( _.omit(taskData, fieldsToOmit.concat(globalFields)))
```

Comment: Clever approach

Answer (score 2):

You can remove properties in a functional manner (immutable) by using destructuring:

```
const {realHours, ...result} = {
    ...taskData, 
    resourceInfo: taskData.resourceInfo.map(
        ({avatar, icon, label, color, ...keep}) => keep
    )
};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer is art.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need lodash to delete fields from an array. I mean you can if you really want to but, it is trivial to loop through the array and delete the fields you want.

@Yasser CHENIK isn't wrong just doesn't do a good job of explaining the solution.

Below I have included a thorough example so you can test for yourself.

*NOTE* this solution mutates the original array but, it is not difficult to use this concept to make an immutable version.

```js
const taskData = {
    "uniqueId": "OrdenTrabajo48",
    "id": 48,
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Dirección Obra Civil",
    "description": "Dirección Obra Civil Afecta: Sorda, Roberto",
    "startDate": "2021-10-16T11:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-06-01T11:00:00.000Z",
    "duration": 227,
    "progress": 73,
    "hours": 0,
    "realHours": 15,
    "predecessor": null,
    "child": [],
    "resourceInfo": [
        {
            "uniqueId": "Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "id": "OrdenTrabajo48Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "name": "Sorda, Roberto",
            "group": "Subgerencia de Planes y Proyectos - SUB_PLAN_PROY_SIT",
            "unit": 4.1667,
            "startDate": "2021-10-16T03:00:00.000+00:00",
            "endDate": "2022-06-01T02:59:59.000+00:00",
            "hours": 0,
            "realHours": 15,
            "avatar": "http://localhost:8091/images/llama.jpg"
        },
        {
            "uniqueId": "Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "id": "OrdenTrabajo48Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "name": "Sorda, Roberto",
            "group": "Subgerencia de Planes y Proyectos - SUB_PLAN_PROY_SIT",
            "unit": 4.1667,
            "startDate": "2021-10-16T03:00:00.000+00:00",
            "endDate": "2022-06-01T02:59:59.000+00:00",
            "hours": 0,
            "realHours": 15,
            "avatar": "http://localhost:8091/images/llama.jpg"
        },
        {
            "uniqueId": "Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "id": "OrdenTrabajo48Persona_1MJ0VE9G0",
            "name": "Sorda, Roberto",
            "group": "Subgerencia de Planes y Proyectos - SUB_PLAN_PROY_SIT",
            "unit": 4.1667,
            "startDate": "2021-10-16T03:00:00.000+00:00",
            "endDate": "2022-06-01T02:59:59.000+00:00",
            "hours": 0,
            "realHours": 15,
            "avatar": "http://localhost:8091/images/llama.jpg"
        },
    ],
    "comments": null,
    "etiquetas": [],
    "baseLineStartDate": null,
    "baseLineEndDate": null
}


const fieldsToOmit = [
    'avatar',
    'icon',
    'label',
    'color',
    'realHours'
]

console.log(taskData.resourceInfo);

taskData.resourceInfo.forEach(info => {
    fieldsToOmit.forEach(field => {
        delete info[field];
    })
});

console.log(taskData.resourceInfo);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Problem is, that the component that compares objects doesn't know the structure of the object, just the path of the fields in string format. (i.e: ``taskData.realHours``.) lodash offers a way to navigate into an object by a path of string, but doesn't offer a way to iterate this way an array.

Comment: ah interesting. I apologize for misinterpreting the request. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers to all.

To solve partially the problem, I created a function that does the following:

- It filters the references that contains `[?]` (i.e: `taskData.resourceInfo[?].avatar`)
- Then obtain the first part of the string (That is, the path to reach the array) and the second part (property name)
- Using `_.get` from lodash it retrieves the length of the array and creates a new fieldReference with the index, so loadash can read it.

```js
private sanitizeArrays(obj: any, fieldReferences: string[]): string[] {
        const fieldsDup = [...fieldReferences];

        // Get Elements that contains [?] in the property name
        const arrays = fieldsDup.filter(ignoredField => ignoredField.match(/\[\?]/g));

        // Remove elements that contain [?] from ignoredFieldsDuplicated
        fieldsDup.forEach((ignoredField, index) => {
            if (ignoredField.includes('[?]')) {
                fieldsDup.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        // Get the properties names without [?]
        const arrayPropertyName = arrays.map(ignoredField => ignoredField.split('[')[0]);
        const afterArrayPropertyName = arrays.map(ignoredField => ignoredField.split(']')[1]);

        // For each array that I have...
        arrayPropertyName.forEach((array, index) => {
            const length = _.get(obj, array).length;

            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                fieldsDup.push(array + '[' + i + ']' + afterArrayPropertyName[index]);
            }
        });

        return fieldsDup;
    }
```

Example input (if the object contains only one element in resourceInfo):

```
'taskData.resourceInfo[?].avatar',
                      'taskData.resourceInfo[?].icon',
                      'taskData.resourceInfo[?].label',
                      'taskData.resourceInfo[?].color',
                      'taskData.resourceInfo[?].fontColor',
                      'taskData.realHours'
```

Example output:

```
taskData.resourceInfo[?].icon
taskData.resourceInfo[?].color
taskData.realHours
taskData.resourceInfo[0].avatar
taskData.resourceInfo[0].icon
taskData.resourceInfo[0].label
taskData.resourceInfo[0].color
taskData.resourceInfo[0].fontColor
```

(javascript `includes()` isn't playing nice deleting the [?])

Also it doesn't work for nested arrays...